# Varying Line Widths According to Attribute Values using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm trying to draw a vector map of Europe on QGIS 1.7.3 with lines symbolizing the transmission of energy (power transmission lines) between the different countries on the map. I am trying to correlate the transmitted power in gigawatts (that I have entered as an attribute for each line) with the thickness of that line (instead of a graduated or categorized color ramp).

Can you tell me if there's a way to do that?

Comment: Not sure about 1.7.3, but 1.8 has a size scale field - I think it's hidden behind the Advanced button.

Comment: Thank you. You're right but I needed it with a legend (like the graduated color option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way I can think of to do this is via the creation of a new thematic style. If your file is already constructed as lines (which it sounds like it is) - all you need to do is go into the layer properties and create a thematic map (colour bands) based on the breaks you want to represent (i.e gigawatts).

Next double click on each symbol to bring up the Symbol selector, click on change (under the image of the current symbol) to bring up Symbol Properties box and select "Simple Line" from the Symbol Layer Type drop down.

From here you can edit the line for width, colour and transparency.

Do this for each of the lines representing the breaks.

Finally, when you've got a style your happy with - use the "Save Style" button (bottom right of the layer properties box), see image below. This will save the style as a "QGIS Layer Style file" (*.qml) - which you can load for different maps in the future.

[image: Style Layer]